# Span fix width in div

Tags: html, css, width

I have div and I need 6 span in there with fix width (now is there some text) - when I remove the text the width is 0px. What can I do? I tried dome things with `display: block;` but it moved spans under them..

Here is a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e8t64vtk/).

```css
#load-1 {
  border-bottom: 3px pink solid;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
#load-2 {
  border-bottom: 3px grey solid;
}
#load-3 {
  border-bottom: 3px grey solid;
}
#load-4 {
  border-bottom: 3px grey solid;
}
#load-5 {
  border-bottom: 3px grey solid;
}
#load-6 {
  border-bottom: 3px grey solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="load">
  <span class="loading" id="load-1">hello</span>
  <span class="loading" id="load-2">hello</span>
  <span class="loading" id="load-3">hello</span>
  <span class="loading" id="load-4">hello</span>
  <span class="loading" id="load-5">hello</span>
  <span class="loading" id="load-6">hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try display:inline-block; and remove height or set not 10px;

Comment: Since you only needs fix width, why not using "display:inline-block"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i got it right but what i understand is that there should at least be an underlined block even if it contains no text. What you need to do is making `div` out of `span` because you can't apply a width to span tags. Then you should give the `div` a `height` and `min-width` in css. With the `min-width` you make sure that even if the `div` is empty it has at least this minimum width.

Look at my fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/e8t64vtk/2/

Comment: I don't know if it is a nice resolution, but it works :)

Comment: I admit that the code can be more compressed, but I think you can do this too :) If this solution worked for you please dont forget to press the arrow up key and accept it as the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block`. It will work.

Comment: `.load > span{ inline-block; }` Will set all elements right